# Enable systemd-backlight@intel_backlight instead of systemd-backlight@acpi_video0

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I have 2 files in `/sys/class/backlight/` - `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight`. `intel_backlight` is the one which controls my screen brightness (echo/cat), however `acpi_video0` is the default.

By default, the service `systemd-backlight@acpi_video0.service` is enabled which *should* save/restore brightness at shutdown/startup, but it doesn't work since it points to the wrong file.

When trying to enable `systemd-backlight@intel_backlight.service` instead,  I get this message:

```
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Side question: Is it normal to have two files in `/sys/class/backlight/`?

Comment: Don't know if it's normal but I have 2 dirs there on my laptop on default install.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you're just missing the `backlight:` part of the command:

```
# systemctl enable systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
```

You may also need to escape the `:`, i.e.:

```
# systemctl enable systemd-backlight@backlight\:intel_backlight.service
```

Since you have two folders in /sys/class/backlight/, you probably have two graphics cards. The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Backlight#Kernel_command-line_options) suggests adding one of the following kernel parameters in your bootloader:

```
acpi_backlight=video
acpi_backlight=vendor
acpi_backlight=native
acpi_backlight=none
```